# VBA - lining up data values in excel

Tags: excel, vba

apologies but I am new to VBA. I have used the site to hep with a problem I have matching 2 columns of data;

```
IP26 5BN    IP26 5BN
IP26 5BN    IP26 5DB
IP26 5DB    IP26 5DB
IP26 5EL    IP26 5EL
IP26 5ET    IP26 5EL
IP26 5ET    IP26 5ET
IP26 5HN    IP26 5ET
IP26 5HR    IP26 5HN
IP26 5HR    IP26 5HR
IP26 5JA    IP26 5JA
IP26 5JA    IP26 5JA
IP26 5NJ    IP26 5NJ
IP27 0DJ    IP27 0DJ
IP27 0DZ    IP27 0DZ
IP27 0ER    IP27 0ER
IP27 0JN    IP27 0JN
```

Items can be in column A & B multiple times and I want to line up any item that is in A with a matching element in B, vice versa and insert a blank row in either A and B when there is an extra "same" value.

I have got to;

```
Sub Expand()
Dim first_col As Range
Dim second_col As Range
Dim row As Integer

Set first_col = Range("A1:A17")
Set second_col = Range("B1:B17")

For row = 1 To second_col.Rows.Count
    If (first_col.Cells(row, 1).Value = second_col.Cells(row, 1).Value Or second_col.Cells(row, 1).Value = first_col.Cells(row, 1).Value) Then
    End If

        If first_col.Cells(row, 1).Value <> second_col.Cells(row, 1).Value Then
        second_col.Cells(row, 1).Insert shift:=xlDown
        ElseIf first_col.Cells(row, 1).Value = second_col.Cells(row, 1).Offset(1, 0).Value Then
        '// code to insert the row
        first_col.Cells(row, 1).Insert shift:=xlDown


    End If
Next row
End Sub
```

But what is happening is the 1st if is not always returning a "true" when I think it should and so the line-up goes part way down or they align to the last row when there are duplicates.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first `If` block is empty.

Do you mean to do this instead?

```
For Row = 1 To second_col.Rows.Count
    If (first_col.Cells(Row, 1).Value = second_col.Cells(Row, 1).Value Or second_col.Cells(Row, 1).Value = first_col.Cells(Row, 1).Value) Then
    'End If <-- Remove this

        If first_col.Cells(Row, 1).Value <> second_col.Cells(Row, 1).Value Then
        second_col.Cells(Row, 1).Insert shift:=xlDown
        ElseIf first_col.Cells(Row, 1).Value = second_col.Cells(Row, 1).Offset(1, 0).Value Then
        '// code to insert the row
        first_col.Cells(Row, 1).Insert shift:=xlDown
        End If '<-- Add this

    End If
Next Row
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly understanding your question. But as I am assuming that you want to insert new row below the active cell.
I think this might help you.

**ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert**